# Centering non-fixed width numbers in div element

Tags: html, css

I'm simulating a paper calendar via CSS.  I'm displaying numbers in a box with a text-shadow.

For a single digit, the number centers just fine, for double digits, the centering is off.

I guess I could trap when it's a double digit and do something like margin-left:-25px but there must be a cleaner way.

```
.calendar
{
    font-family:arial,sans-serif;   
    margin:0 auto;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-box-shadow:10px 10px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:10px 10px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    box-shadow:10px 10px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    line-height:400px;
}
.single-digit
{
    font-size:22em;
}
.double-digit
{
    font-size:20em;
}
```

Centers fine:

```
<div class="calendar"><span class="single-digit">1</span></div>
```

Does not center:

```
<div class="calendar"><span class="double-digit">10</span></div>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dr2uj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem has more to do with visual perception of the centering, almost an optical illusion.

For a variable width font, the roman numerals 0, 2 though 9 are almost all the same width so the space to the left of a double-digit pair like "27" or "30" will be more or less the same as the space to the right.

However, the digit "1" is asymmetric and there is slightly more white space to the right edge of the "1" due to the "hook" that juts out to the top left of the character face.

In a typesetting program, kerning rules would be used to achieve better visual alignment between adjacent characters, but web browsers have at best limited support for kerning.

The fix would require manual adjustments on a character pair basis whenever there is a "1" in the text, for example, a CSS rule for adjusting "1", "10", "11", ..."19", "21", "31".

For character pairs with "1", you could try adjusting `letter-spacing` with a small negative value, and that could improve the look.

Of course, the adjustment is very much dependent on the font used by the browser, and you would have very little control over that unless you specify an embedded font.

Your HTML/CSS is basically as good as it can be, you are simply seeing the aesthetic limits of the current browsers.

**Reference:**

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-kerning-prop

Comment: I can use PHP on the page so I could actually detect if there is a "1" in the number.  If I do that, could I get it as close as possible?

Comment: Using PHP, you can assign a CSS rule as needed, for example, `kern-21-31` for the calendar cells for "21" and "31" and the CSS rule would have some specific `letter-spacing` value that you would have to determine manually to get a pleasing visual layout.  As a first guess, you need a rule for "1", any number pairs with a leading "1", any number pairs with a trialing "1", and maybe a specific rule for "11", so four rules in total.  For a modern calendar, there are only 31 digit-pairs so the problem is manageable.

Comment: What I wound up doing was using a fixed width Google font and a table inside the calendar element with one column per number broken out via PHP.  Overkill but everything lines up nicely.

Comment: Good to hear about how you solved the problem, sometimes overkill is necessary to get the details right!

Answer (score 1):

Try using flexbox like this:

```
.calendar span {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, never heard of flexbox.  Unfortunately it doesn't work in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Dr2uj/2/

Comment: @Tom it looks centered here: http://i.imgur.com/IC7OdiL.png

Maybe the 1 is throwing you off. Try it with 00 instead of 10.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the font is in center position only. If you select the text you can come to know. Otherwise change the HTML like below. Now you will feel it in center.

```
<div class="calendar"><span class="single-digit">2</span></div>
 <div class="calendar"><span class="double-digit">28</span></div>
```